# Overlapping items in RelativeLayout with ImageView and TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have a RelativeLayout that contains two ImageViews (one at the left and the other one at the right) and one TextView (at the center)

This is what I have:

```
                   <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/previous_button"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/img1"
                            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text="@string/name"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                            android:textColor="@color/black" />


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/next_button"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/img2" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have seen the following warning in the TextView (txt1):

> If relative layout has text or button items aligned to left and right
> sides they can overlap each other due to localized text expansion
> unless they have mutual constraints like toEndOf/toStartOf.

I have been searching for information from other posts but I have not seen it clearly how could I solve it in my case. I would appreciate all the possible help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have to give a Start and End for alignment instead of Left and Right because for multilanguage (localization) it won't support.

**Example:**

```
    Case 1: In Arabic, Text starts from Right to Left

    Case 2: In English, Text starts from Left to Right
```

**Changes in TextView:**

Add these lines,

```
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/previous_button"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/next_button"
```

Need to remove this Code in TextView,

```
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Full sample code try this,

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/previous_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img1"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/previous_button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/next_button"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img2"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>
    
</RelativeLayout>
```